# How can we be sure that the non-trivial kernel contains only non-negative integers?

Tags: group-theory

> Let $G$ be a group and consider the additive group of integers
> $\mathbf Z$. For any fixed $s\in G$, show that the function
> $$\begin{align}\phi:\mathbf Z&\to G\\n&\mapsto s^n\end{align}$$ is a
> homomorphism. Deduce from this that if $G$ is finite, then
> $\text{Ker}(\phi)$ is nontrivial and therefore there exists a positive
> integer $m$ such that $s^m=e$. (*Hint*: Can a map from an infinite set
> to a finite set be injective? Consider the answer to this question in
> light of Corolloary 2-8.)

For any $n,m\in\mathbf Z,s\in G$, we have $\phi(n+m)=s^{n+m}$ and $\phi(n)\phi(m)=s^ns^m=s^{n+m}$. Therefore, $\phi$ is a homomorphism.

If $G$ is finite, $\phi$ cannot be injective because $\mathbf Z$ is infinite. Therefore, by Corollary 2-8, the kernel of $\phi$ is non-trivial. (Corollary 2-8 states that a homomorphism of groups is injective if and only if it has trivial kernel.)

However, it implies only that there exists a non-zero integer $m$ such that $s^m=e$, where $e$ is the identity in $G$. How can we be sure that $m$ is positive?

Comment: $s^m=e$ iff $s^{-m}=e$.

Comment: As above, $e$ is its own inverse.

Comment: The question in the title has the answer "You can't, but that's not what they are saying".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your title asks for something which is false: the kernel does not *only* contain non-negative integers.

As was noted in the comments, if it contains some $m\neq 0$, then note that this means that $s^m=e$. Therefore, $s^{-m}=(s^m)^{-1}=e^{-1}=e$, so $-m$ is also in the kernel. Since one of $m$ and $-m$ is positive, you know there is *a* positive integer in the kernel, which is what was asserted; not that every element of the kernel is positive (or nonnegative).

Slightly better is to remember that $\ker(\phi)$ is a *subgroup* of $\mathbb{Z}$. We know that every subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ is of the form $m\mathbb{Z}$ for some $m\geq 0$, and is trivial if and only if $m=0$. So you definitely know that if the kernel is nontrivial, then it is $m\mathbb{Z}$ for some $m\gt 0$, and so every positive multiple of $m$ will be in the kernel.